# Here iOS SDK creating draggable marker

Tags: ios, here-api

I want to create a draggable marker but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
 let marker = NMAMapMarker(geoCoordinates: coordinates, image: markerImage!)

 marker.isDraggable = true            
 mapView.add(mapObject: maker)
 mapView.respond(to: .markerDragBegan) { (drag, map, marker) -> Bool in

 return true
```

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: Feedback: I have downvoted because there are two requests for logs/errors on this page, and they have not been supplied. I appreciate the answer has helped you, but Stack Overflow is intended as a resource to help _many_ people, not just one. So, please reply to my question: are you still able to create these logs, and edit them into your question? If you can do so I will cancel the downvote.

Comment: Hi Enrico, thank you so much for you attention. sorry, I couldn't track the comments. There was no error. It doesn't show. I was able to create market but not drag. The problem was delegate func doesn't work. I fixed it looking at example here map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a reference from below sample code. Also share the error logs that you got while using above code snippet.

```
/**
 * create a NMAMapMarker object, then add it to current active map view.
 */

- (void)addMapMarker {
    //create NMAImage with local cafe.png
    NMAImage* markerImage = [NMAImage imageWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cafe.png"]];
    //create NMAMapMarker located with geo coordinate and icon image
    NMAMapMarker* mapMarker = [NMAMapMarker mapMarkerWithGeoCoordinates:self.mapView.geoCenter icon:markerImage];
    //make marker able to receive dragging gesture from map
    mapMarker.draggable = YES;
    //add NMAMapMarker to map view
    [self.mapView addMapObject:mapMarker];
    //add view and handlers for *MarkerDrag* events:
    [self setupMapMarkerEventHandlersIfNeeded];

    [_mapMarkers addObject:mapMarker];
}
```

Comment: thanks, I got it. and I noticed a bit late to long press marker before drag it :)